# Graphics Driver problem, ATI Radeon HD 3200, small screen size and slows everything down.

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, resolution

Regards.
I am using a:

- 2009 Compaq Presario CQ40-415AU Notebook
- AMD Athlon X2 Dual core Processor 2.1 GHz 1024 MB L2 cache
- 3GB DDR2 RAM
- ATI Radeon + HD 3200 Graphics 256 MB, screen is 14 inch widescreen with resolution of 1280*800.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit on my laptop. It works brilliantly until I installed graphics driver. When I installed the driver, the graphics became slow. Everything slowed down. Even the splash screen resolution changed to something like 640*480.

I have liked Ubuntu since 9.10 and for the freedom it provides and its versatility, but graphics problem remains the same. I even installed Ubuntu on a 50 GB partition with 6 GB swap partition. My HDD is 320 GB. Please tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This obviously got to do with the installation of the proprietary drivers. Rather than the CPU that is mentioned in the post above.

Try to install the (almost) latest AMD catalyst driver:

remove your graphics drivers:
this can be also be done with the synaptic tool(search for synaptic in software center)

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx xserve-xorg-radeon
```

then download and install the newest catalyst drivers:

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
```

unzip the files to a folder.

Make the file inside executable:

```
chmod +x amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86.run
```

Run the Innstallation file:

```
./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86.run
```

Then reboot your machine.

Answer (score 0):

From the way I understand it, everything seems to be working fine until you install the graphics driver. If everything is working anyway why bother with driver installations?

Are you sure you have got the right driver for your OS? If your OS is 32 bit you will need a 32 bit driver, while if your OS is 64 bit, you'll need a 64 bit driver.

Try looking for AMD Linux drivers on this site and see if you can find one for your OS
http://support.amd.com/us/psearch/Pages/psearch.aspx?type=2.7&product=2.7.4.3.3.3.1&contentType=Tech%20Download%20Chipset%20Motherboard

AMD has a reputation for poorly supporting Linux.